# NgSpice transient analysis on BJT Colpitts oscillator

Tags: oscillator, circuit-theory

Can you tell me how can I run a transient analysis on it? What I am curious about is the startup process.
I'd use a simple textbook example BJT circuit, the point is on the simulation setup/commands.
I'd measure the voltages in certain points in ~1000 time points.
Thanks in advance!

ps.: I've seen the topics with similar title, but this isn't a duplicate.

Comment: What is stopping you from doing so? I mean; just run a transient analysis and see what you get. What could be easier?

Comment: Well, I use it in command line and want to do it in the circuit file.

Comment: So, what is preventing you from doing that?

Comment: the syntax. I suppose it is a three-line stuff but I could not make it

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you don't know how to use ngspice? I mean, I don't either because I've never used it but, if this question is genuinely about a colpitts oscillator then what has a lack of understanding of ngspice got to do with the target circuit?

Comment: I'm new to ngspice and all circuit simulators. Have the user manual. I give it another try.

Comment: Perhaps you can add the circuit file also into the question.